# Add subitem to second level

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have primary links created manually. The are links to node (content type 'page')
like

```
-About
--About Us
--About company
```

I need to add subitems `About/About company/company1` and `About/About company/company2` from my module.

Next lines create menu item in first level (in one level with `-About`)

```
$items['about2'] = array(
  'menu_name' => 'primary-links',
  'title' => 'About2',
  'page callback' => 'ninegm_about2',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'weight' => -10,
);
```

Comment: You should report the menu callback defined for "About Us"; when you provide that, I will be able to report the menu callback definition for the menu items you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation at the [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/page_example_menu/6) site. The path of the menu item, and the hierarchical organization, is determined by the key you pass to $items when defining a new menu item. Right now you are making a completely new top-level menu item.

So you need to replace `$items['about2'] with something like this:`

```
$items['About/About company/about2'] = array(
//rest of menu item definition . . .
```

This will make the new menu item a child of the menu items in its path, so it will come out looking like this:

-About

--About Company

---About2

This is assuming the path to your root about page is "About", and the path to your About Company page is "About company". If that isn't true, just replace them with the real paths to those pages.

Comment: Thank you.

Only 'About', 'About company' are menu titles which I enter in Menu settings section of node editing

$items['I dont know this value'] = array(

'title' => 'About', ...);

Comment: It's `$item['menu path']` (`$items['node/%node/edit']`, `$items['user/%user/edit']`, etc).

Comment: Like kiamlaluno said, you can use placeholders in your menu path. Check out http://api.drupal.org/api/function/page_example_menu/6 and http://api.drupal.org/api/group/menu/6 for examples on how to do this.