# how to make drupal pages into menus and submenus like administrator menu

Tags: php, content-management-system, drupal-6, navigation

I'am new to Drupal, i just want to create a website which contains pages like about us, contact us and other static information that may be changed after a long time.

Now i can create the pages and sub pages to main pages. The links are displaying on the top of the logo and the sub pages were showing on the side of the main page.

i installed the [dhtml_menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) module but not working.

are there any changes required to dhtml_menu module to make work for pages?

or

i need to use any other module?

please help me to solve this issue

Thanks.

Comment: no one to answer my question ?? :(

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391302/add-subitem-to-second-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i need to say thanks to **wimvds**. "Thankyou wimvds for your edit it take me to find more modules and themes".

found the solution in a theme "[admire_grunge](http://drupal.org/project/admire_grunge)" the drop down menu needs to be defined in the themes it self.

found some more themes that work like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty confusing. If you just want to display the pages in a tree just like the administration menu (which seems to be what you're asking), then you don't need any extra modules.

Just create your pages and put them all in the primary menu. Then, once your pages are created add the Primary links block (in Administer, Blocks) anywhere you want. That block will display the navigation tree of your pages, just like the administrator menu does.

**edit**

Oh, so you want the drop down menus? Then you don't want dhtml_menu (which will only prevent unneccessary page loading when you open pages), but need something like [simplemenu](http://drupal.org/project/simplemenu). Create your primary links, goto Administer, Site Configuration, SimpleMenu and set the "Menu" setting to "< Primary links >". That will display a drop down menu bar to navigate through your site...

Comment: thanks for the replay. the process you told me is done by me already. but iam not asking about that if you can follow this link http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu i need my primary links menu like the one showing in the above link